# Authenticate User using Windows Authentication in REST WCF Web API

Tags: c#, rest, windows-authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have a requirement to expose some WCF Web API to a 3rd party system. The 3rd party system may validate the users using Windows Authentication.  My Web service will expose a Login method where the username is passed in.  I need to authenticate the passed in user using Windows Authentication.

I try to determine the role for the user by using:

```
 Roles.GetRolesForUser(UserID)
```

I get the following error message:
"Method is only supported if the user name parameter matches the user name in the current Windows Identity. "

How do I validate a passed in username using Windows Authentication?

Comment: The [same way as in ASP.NET Web Forms and MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx)?

Comment: It's slightly different in that the Web Service is called from another application (Java based).  I need to get a list of a users roles for a passed in username (the username will probably not be the current identity).

Answer (score 0):

You have to impersonate the user first, before you can get his/her roles. Or be a user that has sufficient access privileges anyway.

This is a good reference from Microsoft that explains it all:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx